# Find matching values of 2 columns in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading a CSV file with RoR and printing out an HTML table but need to mark when the values of 2 separate columns match with another row.

The CSV looks like

```
name | value1 | value2| value3
bob  |    2   |   3   |   foo
jim  |    4   |   5   |   bar
tim  |    2   |   7   |   foo
```

I want to find when VALUE1 and VALUE3 match the values of VALUE1 and VALUE3 of another row in this CSV file (in this case: "2" & "foo" match on bob and tim)

The result would be something like:

```
name | value1 | value2| value3 | duplicate
bob  |    2   |   3   |   foo  |   Y
jim  |    4   |   5   |   bar  |   N
tim  |    2   |   7   |   foo  |   Y
```

I'm printing the table out

```
<% file.each do |row| %>
<tr>
  <% row.each do |k, v| %>
    <td><% v %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

What I'd like to do is flag the table row when I find the matching columns.

Comment: Not sure I'm following exactly what you're after, but wouldn't you just check `row[:value1] == row[:value3]` and set the `tr` class accordingly, use CSS to get the attributes you want from the class (*e.g.*, highlighting the row).

Comment: Yeah that doesn't make sense, given your wording. You've said *when the values match*, but they clearly don't. What is the criteria for matching? As lurker said, you should simply be able to do some kind of comparison within the body of the `.each` loop to do what you need.

Comment: the values "2" and "foo" match with "bob" and "tim" so those rows would match. but if the values were "7" and "bar" those two would also be a match. i'm not comparing any other columns besides value1 and value4 and those values may be different. i just want to flag when the combination of value2 and value4 are repeated in the file.

Comment: it is not too big. about 16 columns, 100 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another version of the answer above, in plain ruby rather than ERB, so it's easier to test**

I wanted to show my small ruby program to show how I did this. It's not as easy to read in the ERB version and this can be copied and pasted into IRB or piped into a file.

```
 puts '<head></head>'
 puts '<body>'
 puts '<table>'
 puts '<tr><th>#</th><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>Matching Previous Rows:</th></tr>'

file = [%w(Bob foo 32 3), %w(Joe zip 4 foo), %w(Joe baz 4 foo), %w(Steve foo 44 3), %w(Bob baz 32 foo), %w(Mary baz 4 wow), %w(Lisa 34 wow 2), %w(Art 45 foo E),%w(Bob foo 32 3)]
output_file = []

 file.each do |row|
 row.unshift 0x00FFFF  #make first value the background color of 0xFFFFFF
 row.push ''            #add a column for matches
 output_file.each_with_index do |prev_row,i|   # look for current row values in previous entries
      if prev_row[2] == row[2] and prev_row[4] == row[4]
        if prev_row[0] == 0x00FFFF
          prev_row[0] = rand(0xFFFF0)
          row[0] = prev_row[0]
        else
          row[0] = prev_row[0]
        end
        row[-1] += "#{(i + 1)}, "
      end
     end
 output_file << row               #add the new row to the look-back array

 end

 output_file.each_with_index do |output_row,i|
   print "<tr bgcolor=##{output_row[0].to_s(16).upcase}F  >"
   output_row.shift
   print "<td>#{i + 1}</td>"
  output_row.each do |v|           #why the k? you don't use it here.
     print '<td>' + "#{v}" + ' </td>'
  end
  puts '</tr>'
 end
 puts '</table>'
 puts '</body>'
```

[image: Table produced by this code]

Comment: I ended up with a hybrid of this and it works great. thanks for the help Beartech

Comment: Glad I could help, forced me to learn something too. Didn't think I could get the color coding to stay the same for future duplicates. Thing is, I have wanted to do this in Excel before and I don't think it could be done very easily. This should be a standard Conditional Format option in Excel. Going to put this into a library for the next time I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I am reminded of a certain XKCD comic about determining if a photo was taken in a National Park,
And if the photo is of a bird... LOL

So you need a bit more complex data structure to do comparison of each row with all previous rows.
**OK, final edit:** I added code to only set a new color if this is the first time a set of values repeats, that way if it repeats again it will get the same color. Also added code that appends columns showing what rows also match.

```
<% output_file = [] %>  
<%  color_offset = 26214 %>

<%  file.each do |row| %>
  <%  row.unshift 0x00FFFF     # add last 4 digits of bgcolor as first item in each row   %>
  <%  row.push ''       #add a column at the end for row match numbers  
  <%  output_file.each_with_index do |prev_row,i| # look for current row values in previous entries  %>

    <%  if prev_row[2] == row[2] and prev_row[4] == row[4]  %>
          <% if prev_row[0] == 0x00FFFF %>
            <%  prev_row[0] -= color_offset  %>
            <%  row[0] = prev_row[0]   %>
          <% else %>
            <% row[0] = prev_row[0] %>
          <% end %>

          <%  color_offset -= 52     %>
          <%  row[-1] += "#{(i + 1)}, "  %>
    <%  end   %>       
   <%  end %>

  <%  output_file << row   # add the new row to the look-back array %>

<%  end  %>

<%  output_file.each do |output_row|  %>
     <tr bgcolor=#FF<% output_row[0].to_s(16).upcase %>  >
     <% output_row.shift %>
     <% output_row.each do |v|    # why the k? you don't use it here.  %>            
     <td> <% v %> </td>                
     <%  end   %> 
     </tr>
<%  end    %>
```

So you take each row, loop through the array of rows previously checked, if it matches change both their first items to a matching 4 digit color in hex (G and B, R is added at the end), then copy the new row into the array of rows previously checked.

This breaks if a row matches more than once, as it will only give the same color to the new match and the one previous. BUT I added a final column that tells you which row each one matched previously. So if it is highlighted you can jump back to that row.

There are other ways to do the highlighting, maybe copy the new color forward, that way more than two of the exact same row would be the same color.

Comment: File size will determine how fast, or more appropriately how SLOW this will be. If you did this on the back end you could just have a helper method that prints the table. It would load the CSV into a temp table in the db, then you could easily set a column value of bg_color for each row in the table. Then just print the table with the appropriate variable substitution.

Comment: this may work because the file is not that large. i'll give it a shot.

Comment: however, it'll grab the dupe but not what it is the dupe OF.

Comment: That was not clear in your question. This is basically like the Excel "highlight duplicate values" in Conditional Formatting. It just highlights values that appear somewhere else. If you want a indicator of WHAT line is duplicating, that is a more complex situation. Do the values ever repeat more than once? Where do you want to list the duplicate rows? A simple highlight will not do what you want. If you are a not looking to delve into Rails, I don't blame you for not wanting to dig into it. But really, this is a poor way to go about this level of data analysis.

Comment: When I have a second I can code a little into the answer that would start with a marker color something like #003333, then each time the marker color is used to mark a couple of matches, it would then increment the color by a certain amount. That way you could see which rows match.